# How to make save game in java applet game?

Tags: java, applet

I have been looking from everywhere how would it be possible to make a save game file in java applet but of course it is not possible to just make an xml file... (or would it? please tell me!)

I don't want to make the "player" to log in to game with username, password and stuff like that, that goes to some server and things like that...

Just what would be the easiest and the most simple way to save a couple of variables so the player don't need to start the game from the beginning every time? (Becouse in an rpg game it would be so lame...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you can't save files, because of the security restrictions. Unless it's running as a trusted applet, which is problematic. The short answer is no, you can't write files, because Java applets runs in sandbox. From sandbox you don't see the local file system.

Maybe you can store your save game in a cookie? [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/accessingCookies.html) you have an official tutorial how to handle cookies from Java.

This [link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/231473-making-a-save-game-function-for-an-applet/) can be also helpful, somebody had a similar question.